# Visual Studio No symbols loaded

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I am trying to debug a project using Visual studio 2010. When I start debugging the breakpoints were disabled with the message

```
No symbols have been loaded for this document.
```

I tried rebuilding it multiple times. But I am not successful with that.

I also tried looking in Debug->Windows->Modules. I am not able to see the module for that project under modules.

Can anyone help me fix it.

i went through this [Visual Studio No Symbols have been loaded for this document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8341686/visual-studio-no-symbols-have-been-loaded-for-this-document)
but here in that case he can see the modules.

Comment: Did you build with debug information on?  Are the pdb files in the same directory as the executable you're trying to debug?

Comment: Yes I buid it with debug information on and also the pdb files were in the same directory as executable is.

Comment: and the code is built into the executable itself, and not to a different DLL?

Answer (score 1):

> I also tried looking in Debug->Windows->Modules. I am not able to see the module for that project under modules.

Check if you applied the **Set as Startup Project** on your project before you started your debug run.