# How to fix "Source information is missing from the debug information"?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-debugging

[image]

Hi

I tried so many solutions to fix this problem but none is working. Sometimes I can debug without any hesitation and sometimes it shows this as shown in the pic.

What is the best solution for this?

Thanks

[image]

Comment: @ Rehaan, Disable the option "Require source files to exactly match the original version" under TOOLS->Options->Debugging->General, please also enable the Microsoft Symbols Server under TOOLS->Options->Debugging->Symbols. Debug it again. If you want to view the Exception code line, you could use the Exception throw under Debug->Exceptions.

Comment: any update? What about this issue in your side?:)

Comment: It is not working. still same. @JackZhai-MSFT

Comment: @ Rehaan, Could you share the detailed output messages from the Output window?  Uncheck 'Enable address level debugging' and Check 'Enable Just My Code' and "use Manage/Unmanage mode"under TOOLS->Options->Debugging. Debug it again.

Comment: After I enable "Just my code" I got the error as shown above. Disabled again. https://i.stack.imgur.com/E1Kb8.png

Comment: if you enable "break when this exception is thrown", and then re-debug your app again, does it throw the exception in the specific code line? Can you share the main code or a simple sample? We need to resolve the exception firstly.

Comment: After enabling "Just my code" I haven't seen the error again. If it pops up again, I will do as you mentioned above and let you know. Thanks

Comment: You are welcome, Rehaan. If it works well, you could post the answer. If not, feel free to let me know, I will follow up it in time. Have a nice day:)

Comment: Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8341844/3058836) approach.